# Reuse web agents that PRINT to the browser in XPages Lotus

Tags: xpages, document, lotus, agents

When upgrading classic Domino applications to XPages one particular problem arises constantly: "what to do with the PRINT statements in existing agents that write back directly to the browser?" I have 200 agents in my nsf file which all uses Print statement in their code.
I have investigated found the link http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH
but it is not possible for me to change agent code as it is also used from forms.
I have to re-use these agents from xpages on button click and also have to pass document.
Is there any way or alternative which can solve my problem.
help is required.

We have Agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc:NotesDocument) method which can run the agent from xpage and passing an in-memory document. I create an im-memory document

```
   var doc = database.createDocument();
   doc.replaceItemValue("StartDate",startDate.getDateOnly())
   doc.replaceItemValue("EndDate",endDate.getDateOnly())
   doc.replaceItemValue("ReportName",reportName)
    var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent("("+reportName+")");

    agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc);
```

This in-memory document i can pass to the agent. But the issue I am facing currently that my agents are used to print directly which is not possible through xpage i assume.
Is there any alternative way to pass in-memory document to agent and able to print directly to browser through xpages.
Help needed please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use XPages.. then USE XPages... Meaning migrate the agents to the XPages way of doing things.  There can be a lot of coexhistance between XPages and Notes Client or I supposed even Classic Domino Web.  But if you're set on keeping 200 Agents which are NOT really part of XPages Best practices, then it sounds to me like you shouldn't be using XPages at all.

EDIT: 
This link:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_and_Calling_Agents_Using_an_In-Memory_Document

Talks about calling an Agent from XPages and being able to use the in memory document.  Maybe that will help but if it's heavily used performance will not be great since an agent loads and unloads for each call.  It's still a bad idea to do.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to call agent
Xpage -> Lotus Form -> Agent call on form load or any other method in which the agent can work on the document context. I can create the document in the form using url parameter from xpage to lotus form.
We have 100 DB so changing each DB would not be correct solution.
I am new to Xpages any help will be of great help.

Comment: I added a link to a document on how to call an agent from xpages.  The correct solution is to not try and force XPages in this way. It sounds like a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

create a java class that calls your agent and read the output from your agents in an input stream and display the stream in computed field in Xpages.

here is a sample java class that will retrive the output from your agent

```
package com.thomas;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

    public class getAgentData{

        public String getData() throws IOException {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/mydatabase.nsf/myagent?openagent");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String content = new String();
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content+=inputLine;
                }
                in.close();
                return content;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If you add your java class as a bean in faces-config.xml you can call it using a computed field in your xpages like this

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:getAgentData().getData()}"></xp:text>
```

Comment: Could you please help me with an example of the Java class. I also need to pass the document to the agent which I fetch in agent using NotesSession.DocumentContext property.
Is there any alternative way to call agent
Xpage -> Lotus Form -> Agent call on form load in which the agent can work on the document context.
I am new to Xpages any help will be of great help.

Comment: There are 2 challenges with Thomas' class :-) a) it only works on databases you can access anonymously and it might fail on large replies. If you want to travel down that path, use the Apache HTTP client

Comment: how do we pass a document in this java class. I wan the agent to work on the in-memory document also.

Comment: not sure what you mean, in memory documents are available in forms, not in xpages. In xpages you work with data sources. if you create a new data source in you xpage you have an in-memory document. If you need to get hold of a specific document in this solution you need to send the unid in the print statements and parse that using the java class.

Comment: We have Agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc:NotesDocument) method which can run the agent from xpage and passing an in-memory document. I create an im-memory document

Comment: ok, then you need to use another approach, my answer was on how to get your print statements into xpages

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your agent a little. Instead of `Print "Something"` you would use `someobj.print "Something"` - which should be a manageable task using search/replace. The detailed steps have been documented [in this blog entry](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH).

Now you state that you need to dual use the agent. Not that hard, once you move beyond copy and paste programming.

When you check the class - it looks for documentcontext. When you call the agent directly, the document context is not there. So you check if you have the document - if not it is classic and you add a print statement to the class, if it is there you save to the context.

The code is `myObject.printResult = true` to print - or you set it to true per default (but then you pollute your log :-) )

If you provide a context doc when calling the agent, then you would provide an item (e.g. `DontPrint=1`) from your XPages and check that one. If it is there, only save to the context, otherwise add the print statement.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to call agent Xpage -> Lotus Form -> Agent call on form load or any other method in which the agent can work on the document context. I can create the document in the form using url parameter from xpage to lotus form. We have 100 DB so changing each DB would not be correct solution. I am new to Xpages any help will be of great help

Comment: "Quite some work to do" doesn't make a solution "not correct". If you have setup a proper development environment - that is one with all database designs under version control - you can run through the agents in the ODP with a script (any language) to adjust the code. There is no need to use the form in between.